# Other Way to Use services

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I would like to load the appropriate service after the constructor of a component.

I know that the way to use a service in a component is to call it in the constructor. But I would like to be able to load this or that service according to, a data from my component.
In order to be able to call the appropriate service later on.

Rough example of a component of a conversation

```
_currentSendingService; // a service    
constructor(private _alert : AlertService) 
{ 
 this.foo();
}

foo() {
   if (condition) {
     this._currentSendingService = SmsService // not working idea of what i want
     }
    else {
     this._currentSendingService = EmailService
        }
 }
sendMessage() {
  this._currentSendingService.send(message)
 }
```

A way doing it is by putting all services in the constructor and to instantiate a var.

```
constructor(private _alert : AlertService, private _smsService:SmsService, private _emailService:EmailService) 
{ 
 this.foo();
}
```

And doing this in foo();

```
foo() {
   if (condition) {
     this._currentSendingService = this._smsService
     }
    else {
     this._currentSendingService = this._emailService
        }
 }
sendMessage() {
  this._currentSendingService.send(message)
 }
```

But if i use a lot of services, is it optimize doing like that ? (imagine if i have like 20 services available, but only one of them is used depending of the scenarios) And with this way the constructor of each service will trigger, it's a behaviour i may not want

Example :  we load a component, according to its data we want to use the SmsService as _currentSendingService, because the type of message we have in the conversation is only in SMS.
So when I use _currentSendingService.send("message"); It will use SmsService.send("message") method. 
If you can tell me how to proceed, I can't find it. All the documents I find about the services tell me to register it in the constructor. 
Thank you for taking the time to read my problem

Comment: Rather than injecting all the possible services, you should inject a service factory that has responsibility for resolving the particular service your class needs.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Thanks,That's exactly what I wanted, I'll see how it works. I will edit my  post or make an answer if I make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Factory pattern form GOF design patterns in order to do that create and interface

```
export interface IMessage{
   send();
}
```

then in your `smsservice` and `emailservice`

```
export class SMSService implements
{
  send(){
   //your implementation
  }
}
```

the same should be done for email service then create messageservicefactory

```
export class MessageServiceFactory{
    getInstance(yourcondition):IMessage{
      if(condition){
    return new SMSService();
       }else{
    return EmailSerivce();
    }//you can also use switch case here
}
```

then inject your messageserivcefactory to your component and use something like

```
   _messageService:IMessage;
    constructor(private _messageServiceFactory :MessageServiceFactory) 
    {
    _messageService=__messageServiceFactory.getInstance(condition);
    }
    sendMessage() {
      this._messageService.send(message)
     }
```

[Example here](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/factory-method-design-pattern-dotnet)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser looks like, it's the best way doing it, i will try to implement that. I never use interfaces before. It's time to get started. If i get an issue i will be back :)

Comment: I make it works, exactly what i want Thanks.
I have still one more question. If my service EmailService have something in its constructor like (private http : Httpclient) I have to implement it in the MessageService constructor and in the getInstance();  i have to  return EmailSerivce(this.http); It's what i've done (it's working) but is there a better way ?

Comment: yes you can do it in that way another way around is instead of creating `new` object just inject these services to message service you can decide as per requirements